# Why does my code throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I've got a `JFrame` and automatically a content pane generated by Eclipse.

```
public JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
public static Game frame;
```

The main method creates the new frame:

```
frame = new Game();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Creating the new instance:

```
public Game() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    contentPane.setSize(500, 500);
    setContentPane(contentPane);
```

At the end of this I want to create a new object of my Field.java (which extends `JLabel`)

```
new Field(50, 50, 64, 64);
```

Field.java:

```
public Field(int x, int y, int x2, int y2) {
    setBounds(x, y, x2, y2);
    Game.frame.contentPane.add(this);
}
```

I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do. When adding the field to the `contentPane` of the `Game` class, I get a `NullPointerException`. I think, `contentPane` is `null`. But why? And what could I do to avoid this?

Error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Hackbaellchen.Field.<init>(Field.java:23)
at Hackbaellchen.Lemmings.<init>(Game.java:73)
at Hackbaellchen.Lemmings$1.run(Game.java:27)
```

Field.java:23 is `Game.frame.contentPane.add(this);`
Game.java:73 is `new Field(50, 50, 64, 64);`

Comment: can u give the exact error message, Where exactly which line whic hobject is having nullpointer. it helps in debugging

Comment: frame is static so in your program order executuion  Game.frame.contentPane.add(this); is getting called first. make it non static or define the object for it before calling it
in short your program is terminated before calling thre constructor of game class

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: There's now an error message.

Comment: What's the Game.java:27 line?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE]. 2) See also [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to try to back-reference the `Game` instance from the `Field`'s constructor. This kind of logic is bad practice anyway and here it tries to access the static field before it is set (from within the codepath of the `Game` constructor).

You should first create the `Field` instance, then assign it to `Game` from a point in code where it's known to exist. So move the line

```
Game.frame.contentPane.add(this);
```

to such a place (and replace `this` with the name of the `Field` variable).

Comment: Like that (in Game class): contentPane.add(new Field(50, 50, 64, 64));
I can't see this label on my frame..

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have provided, without knowing the exact error stack trace, I think that the origin of your NullPointerException is at:

```
contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

When later on you call the Game instance, having that null field throws the exception.

Comment: This is just the layout.. I prefer using coordinates.. are you sure?

Comment: Although I can't be sure since the information you provided is somewhat incomplete, I mostly get nullPointerExceptions from this kind of declarations. @Hackbaellchen